# Package deployed in azure sql server fails as it cant access remote excel file

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, ssms-2017, ssis-2017

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

I have deployed my SSIS project & package in Azure sql server. When I execute it  through visual studio 2017 in my local machine it is executed successfully. Whereas it shows the above error if I execute the deployed package manually in Azure sql server SSISDB through SSMS tool.

The package in azure sql server is not able to access my excel file present in local folder because both are in different system.

How to write my excel connection string so that package deployed in azure sql server can access the excel file in remote system

Note: When the package is executed in the system where there is excel file , it is executed successfully. When it is executed from azure sql server manually through SSMS it fails, because it can't access the excel which is in remote system

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jxhn.png)

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are trying to run SQL Server in an Azure VM or if you are using Azure SQL Database (aka SQL Azure) as the target?

Comment: I am using Azure SQL Database aka SQL Azure

Comment: Unfortunately sql azure does not currently support linked servers. So you would need to access excel from outside the database layer